# ¿Cómo hago para que al salir de un alert de Javascript no se pueda cerrar la ventana principal?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy creando una página donde se muestra un `alert`. Necesito que no se pueda cerrar la ventana padre sin que se haya cerrado el alert. ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Comment: No sep uede, SIEMPRE se puede cerrar la ventana padre sin importar el proceso que este corriendo. Saludos.

Comment: Estoy intentandolo hacer pero para el navegador google chrome ? Como sería ?

Answer (score 3):

Entendiendo "ventana padre" como la ventana del navegador... he escuchado que no es ético impedir que un usuario cierre una ventana, una opción es mostrarle otro mensaje si quiere cerrar la ventana, por ejemplo con un [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) de JS

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var e = e || window.event;
  // For IE and Firefox
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Tu mensaje para el usuario';
  }
  // For Safari
  return 'Tu mensaje para el usuario';
};
</script>
```

También prueba leyendo la documenación del [onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload), importante ver que si el usuario tiene pop-up window blocker, no va a funcionar tu JS.